# How should I notify a changed setting across projects inside a solution?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I am currently developing two projects: Let's call one *Configuration* and the other is the *Main*. Both of them belong to the same solution.

In *Configuration*, the user inputs in all configuration settings. These settings are to be used in the *Main*, like visual settings, language and connection data. These settings are stored at the project settings, and when the user closes the application, I serialize the configuration into a XML file.

The problem is: I know that I could access, while in *Main*, *Configuration* properties, get all this data, and write into *Main* settings for quick access. But I need to read from this XML file that we made at *Configuration* application closing event. But this XML path folder can be changed by the user.

How can I keep *Main* updated of this folder location? Can I bind this property somehow? How can I keep *Main* updated about a folder changed of a file from *Configuration*?

**Edit:** As no one posted a answer, I am making a edit to try to clarify my question, but the problem has been solved. But I would appreciate any other possible solutions. I have made another edit to cleanup this question.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question right but: You use project settings for each project. Cant you set the access modifier of the setting(s) to public? That way you can access it from wherever you like.

Comment: Hello @hSchroedl. Already tried that, but I cannot access. Saw this comment in another question... Tried that to no avail. :( Perhaps I'm doing something wrong in that front? Both projects belongs to the same solution. If I am in main, and want to do something like `Properties.Settings.Default.XMLPath = Config.Properties.Settings.Default.MyXMLPathConfig` should work? Sorry, I'm still a newbie.

Comment: I am scared to ask, but do you allow user to save file *somewhere* without providing some way to inform `Main` about location? =D If so, perhaps you could use `Registry` to store that. `Main` will check configuration location, load it, happily runs.

Comment: Um... Using Registry could work! I'll look into it. And that is my doubt, how to inform Main about this location. :) Thanks a bunch. Shouldn't you provide this as a answer? I'll wait for other answers too.

Comment: Whatever they save to, you can simultaneously save a copy in %appdata% local.  The main can have a file watcher in %appdata% local and get notified whenever it is changed or saved.

Comment: @Sinatr Thanks for that help. I took a look about writing on Registry, and at closing event, I fire with my writer the Registry writer. On _Main_, I fire a loader that read the location from the Registry to get the XML. It works. On the next app version, I'll make us of %äppdata%, as instructed by Gayot.

Comment: @Sinatr I finished it, and we are using Registry Keys. If you want to post this as a answer, so the question won't appear as unswered.... Anyway, thanks! I'll wait a bit. If you don't want to post that as a answer, I will answer myself!